# jQuery Scroll not working for mobile devices

Tags: jquery

jQuery Scroll not working for mobile devices

here is my code:

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        alert("scrolled");
    }
});
```

can any one help pls...

Comment: did you find the solution? i'm too struggling with this..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of the incompatibility between different browsers and platforms.

Try to use `$(window).scroll` instead of `$(document).scroll`:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        alert("scrolled");
    }
});
```